# Pointer to an array of structs

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, struct, allocation

I am attempting to continuously free memory and allocate memory. I keep getting the error: access violation reading location 0xblahblahblah.

Here is essentially what I am doing:

```
Block *treeBlocks1;
treeBlocks1 = new Block[topology1.length()];
//I am able to use "treeBlocks1" as needed in my code to calculate cost

while(true)
{
    delete [] treeBlocks1;
    treeBlocks1 = new Block(newTopology.length());
    //And now I get an error when trying to calculate cost using treeBlocks1
}
```

What could be my problem?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple....changing the `()` to `[]`.... duh.

```
treeBlocks1 = new Block[newTopology.length()];
```

Answer (score 0):

`new Block(newTopology.length());` isn't allocating an array, it's allocating a single `Block` using a constructor that takes a `size_t` (or a similar integer value) as an argument.

You probably mean `new Block[new Topology.length()]`. Or better yet, use `std::vector` so you don't have to worry about allocating and freeing memory yourself.

Comment: haha thank you so much for pointing that out. I spend too much time on this. I just need to change my parenthesis to brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Inside while you used () instead of using [], infront of block, **treeBlocks1 = new Block(newTopology.length());** check it and change () to [].

`treeBlocks1 = new Block[newTopology.length()]`;